# Automatically Pressing Submit on a third party survery page

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I am trying to figure out a way to have someone auto complete a survey and then press submit. I have figured out have to get the information prefilled. The issue comes in when pressing submit. 
I followed this link [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449341/javascript-to-automatically-login-to-third-party-site?fbclid=IwAR3PMRX5re2o71C1DyqPrQKINMch-AeDGTrebZbHKl9tF_LRssfgPkiVyr8) However, I get this error `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`

I realized that the page I followed is old and this error is telling me that what I am doing is an attack on the site. However, this is not an attack I am trying to do but instead just press the submit button.

The survery is on LimeSurvey if it helps.

Does anyone have any ideas on either this way or another way of pressing submit on a third party page?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the same-origin-policy this is not allowed and if there was a workaround, it would render the same-origin-policy useless.

The only thing I can think of is using something that controls the browser like the browser testing framework [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). But that requires installation on the local system.

Comment: Really? So there is no code I can use out there which I can just press the submit button?